# Is it possible to execute a database insert from the Windows command-line?

Tags: mysql, command-line, insert

Normally if you wanted to execute a MySQL command you would just open up the MySQL command-line, but I'm trying to execute the command via Windows command-line.

It's possible that this is not possible, but I imagined the code looking something like this:

```
mysql -u root -pInsertPassword; USE InsertDatabaseName; INSERT INTO InsertDatabaseName (col1, col2) VALUES('data1', 'data2' )
```

Question, feedback, request -- just comment, thanks!!

System Setup:

- **MySQL:** 5.1.53-community MySQL Community Server (GPL)
- **Window:** 7

Comment: Unless this is different under Windows and I forgot, it's not necessary to `USE dbname;` as a SQL statement from the CLI.  Just include the dbname as the last argument to mysql: `mysql -u root -pPwd dbname`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows supports pipes, so you can do:

`echo insert into ... | mysql -uroot -p databaseName`

Comment: +1 Great, thanks -- it works!! Here's the sample code I used: "echo show databases; | mysql -u root -pINSERTPASSWORD" ...note that there's no space between the "-p" and INSERTPASSWORD.