# Is it possible to execute a database insert from the CentOS command-line?

Tags: mysql, linux, command-line, insert, centos

Normally if you wanted to execute a MySQL command you would just open up the MySQL command-line, but I'm trying to execute the command via Windows command-line.

Just got this got this code working on the [Windows command-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181477/is-it-possible-to-execute-a-database-insert-from-the-windows-command-line), but also need a port of it for CentOS:

```
echo INSERT INTO InsertTableName (Column001, Column002) VALUES('Value001', 'Value002'); | mysql -u InsertUserName -pInsertPassword InsertDatabaseName
```

Question, feedback, request -- just comment, thanks!!

System Setup:

```
* MySQL: 5.1.53-community MySQL Community Server (GPL)
* CentOS: 5.5 (64-bit)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to quote the insert statement:

```
echo "INSERT INTO InsertTableName (Column001, Column002) VALUES('Value001', 'Value002');" | mysql -u InsertUserName -pInsertPassword InsertDatabaseName
```

Comment: +1 Great, thanks!! -- just confirmed it works, again, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it this way (as from the mysql man page; I tested this):

```
mysql -u InsertUserName -pInsertPassword InsertDatabaseName  -e "INSERT INTO InsertTableName (Column001, Column002) VALUES('Value001', 'Value002');"
```